# reveal function or Keyframe animation css not working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to get an animation to run on page element in wordpress. I cannot work out why it is not working. i added this code in new blanket page.
i want to load section when scroll to that section, the content load with animation
However, this animation is working in an visual studio code correctly.

The code is:

CSS:

```
    section1 {
        min-height: 400px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        }
        .reveal {
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0;
        }
       .reveal.active {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .active.fade-right {
      animation: fade-right 1s ease-in;
      -webkit-animation: fade-right 1s ease-in;
    
    }
    @keyframes fade-right {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(200px);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(-100px);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
```

script :

```
     function reveal() {
      var reveals = document.querySelectorAll(".reveal");
    
      for (var i = 0; i < reveals.length; i++) {
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        var elementTop = reveals[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var elementVisible = 150;
    
        if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
          reveals[i].classList.add("active");
        } else {
          reveals[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
      }
    }
```

html:

```
    <section class="section1">
        <h1>Scroll Down to Reveal Elements &#8595;</h1>
      </section>
     
      <section class="section1">
        <div class="container reveal fade-right">
          <h4>Caption</h4>
       
            <div class="text-box">
              <h3>Section Text</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore
                eius molestiae perferendis eos provident vitae iste.
              </p>
            </div>    
          </div> 
        </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a trick to this situation.
i inserted style code inline.
now i insert my style sheet via external link and animation in WordPress page worked fine for me.
classic page builder in wordpress disable @keyframe and animation.